# Get common lists in Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of StuedntInfo table

[image]

and i have List of Classes

```
var classesList = GetClasses2nd(2017);
```

Reasult is

- ClassId = 5
- ClassId = 4
- ClassId = 8

Now is it possible to get list of StudentInfo records dynamically  where classes id are present in StudentInfo table?
Also if possible to get list of Location objects as well?

Comment: You need to use a JOIN.  See msdn : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've had to make a few assumptions about your model / db context, but something like this should work:

```
var classesList = GetClasses2nd(2017);

//get the class Ids
var classIds = classesList.Select(x => x.ClassId);

var students = db.Students
                .Include(x=>x.Location) //assuming you have this navigation property on your model
                .Where(x=> classIds.Contains(x.ClassID))
                .ToList();
```

Note: The `Include` will only work if you have a navigation property set on your model.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx

Answer (score -1):

try Code:

```
  var classidList= ( From p in db.student
                     group p by p.studentid into jj 
                    select new {
                                classid=jj.max(c=>c.classid)
                               }).ToList();
```